# How can I describe three different situations on a cell in Numbers

Tags: numbers

We have business rules as follows:

- If it is bigger than £35 we charge 75% of it
- If it is smaller than £20 we charge 70% of it
- If is is between 20 to 35 we charge 72% of it

I don’t know how to set up a formula to automate this calculation in numbers. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is it? A cell?

Answer (score 3):

Let B3 be the cell you are trying to reference.

```
=IF(B3>35,B3×0.75,IF(B3<25,B3×0.7,B3×0.72))
```

More information on using IF functions can be found in the [formulas reference for Numbers](https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/8.1/#/ffa5834118)